# Overlapped Nested Tab Bar Controllers

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, controller, tabbar

I’ve created a UITaBarController with 4 UIViewControllers and embedded in (Editor -> Embed In -> Tab Bar Controller) them with another Tab Bar Controller. So, I have two levels of Tab Bar Controllers.

But, the second level of tab bar is being hidden by the first level and I don't know how to fix that.

How can I fix that?

Pictures:
 
- [Overlapped Nested Tab Bars (Issue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr8Q6.png)
 
- [Mockup (Goal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GML3V.png)
 
- [Main Story Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDbJz.png)
 
- [Project Source Code Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QTkQWkqO1ioFK-cOMJy9o4I0tbGyOEcZ/view?usp=sharing)
 
- [How to reproduce in Xcode the nested tab bar controllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvCux.png)

Answer (score 0):

I could go forward solving this situation inserting a Tab Bar Controller with a Container View in the Tab Bar’s View Controller and embedding a Tab Bar Controller on the Container View. So, I have perfect nested standard Tab Bar Menus using storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for answering however, it is better to include the relevant code as an example for others. It would also be great to have a short explanation why you did what you did. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more.